# Errors when installing SimpleElastix on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux

I follow the instruction from the official website

```bash
$ git clone https://github.com/SuperElastix/SimpleElastix
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ../SimpleElastix/SuperBuild
$ make -j4
```

the `make -j4` instructions did not work, and the error seems that the error happened during the linking stage.

```bash
[ 67%] Building CXX object Examples/CMakeFiles/BufferImportExport.dir/BufferImportExport.cxx.o
/usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<unsigned char>::Zero'/home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<unsigned char>::Zero'

/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here

/usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<signed char>::Zero'/home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<signed char>::Zero'

/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here

/usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<unsigned short>::Zero'/home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<unsigned short>::Zero'

/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here

/usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<short>::Zero'/home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<short>::Zero'

/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here

/usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<unsigned int>::Zero'/home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<unsigned int>::Zero'

/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here

/usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<int>::Zero'/home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<int>::Zero'

/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here

/usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<unsigned long>::Zero'/home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<unsigned long>::Zero'

/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here

/usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<long>::Zero'/home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<long>::Zero'

/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here

/usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<float>::Zero'/home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<float>::Zero'

/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here

/usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /usr/bin/ld.gold：错误： /home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<double>::Zero'/home/yujinze/build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-5.1.a(itkNumericTraits.cxx.o): multiple definition of 'itk::NumericTraits<double>::Zero'

/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here/usr/bin/ld.gold: ../lib/libSimpleITKCommon-2.0.a(sitkImageExplicit.cxx.o): previous definition here

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[5]: *** [Examples/CMakeFiles/tfx.dir/build.make:374：bin/tfx] 错误 1
make[5]: *** [Examples/CMakeFiles/elx.dir/build.make:374：bin/elx] 错误 1
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4322：Examples/CMakeFiles/tfx.dir/all] 错误 2
make[4]: *** 正在等待未完成的任务....
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4247：Examples/CMakeFiles/elx.dir/all] 错误 2
```

I have no idea how to solve the error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)